# How to query a Python mongoengine Queryset?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, mongoengine

How can I query a queryset returned by MongoEngine? Based on the documentation I couldn't find any information about querying querysets: http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet

```
import datetime
thirty_days_in_the_past = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)

def last_messages(from_date):
    messages = Messages.objects(sent_at__gt=from_date)
    return messages

messages = last_messages(thirty_days_in_the_past)
```

Then I would like to get messages with a particular subquery such as finding an author_id "ABC":

```
messages.query(author_id="ABC")
```

The reason I am looking to do this as the initial query itself is used by a component and a subquery of it is used by another component and I would like to reuse the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the queryset with the narrowed-down query or use `.filter()` (which is just an alias). The mongoengine [documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/querying.html#) does not really mention the possibility to just call the queryset with another query (and the existence of `filter`) for some reason.

```
author_messages = messages(author_id="ABC")
# or
author_messages = messages.filter(author_id="ABC")
```

"Fun fact", the django orm, which mongoengine took heavy inspiration from (the whole query language, including the `__` keyword syntax), does mention the `filter` method in its [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) :)